# Is it possible to use iPhone 6 with FaceTime without a cellular SIM card?

Tags: iphone, facetime, sim

I have an iPhone 6 with FaceTime purchased from Saudi Arabia.

I don't have a cellular SIM in my phone, only a data SIM card.

My question now is if I go out of the Kingdom to any other country, will my iPhone get locked? Will my FaceTime stop working even if I'm connected to the internet?

Will I have to have a jailbreak?

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to fix this problem with these troubleshooting steps:

- Open Settings -> FaceTime. Enter an Apple ID and login. In the same dialog toggle FaceTime off and then on.
- Open Settings -> Messages. Enter an Apple ID and login. In the same dialog toggle Messages off and then on.

I have resolved my problem activating Messages but FaceTime continues to wait for activation. I believe that FaceTime may be waiting for an SMS in order to verify the mobile number. My mobile number shows a busy icon in its Settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When your iPhone is activated, you could use FaceTime when you are connected to internet. Keep in mind that your iPhone could be simlocked by your provider, and that your iPhone possibly won't work in other countries, see [this](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/) link to find if your iPhone is supported in the country you want to visit.

Answer (score 0):

As I know if your phone can connect to Internet you can use facetime. No matter your SIM card is data or cellular, or even you don't have SIM card, you can use facetime as long as your device can connect to Internet.

Comment: Where did you get your information regarding not needing a SIM card?

Comment: I also have this problem. I did not activate FaceTime on my iPhone while I was using it as a temporary replacement. Now my daughter uses it without a SIM (wifi only). FaceTime says "Waiting for activation..." and will not proceed.

Comment: It appears that the "even you don't have SIM card" part is not true, according to numerous other experiences around the inter webs.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7931443